# Mac does not recognize DisplayPort through a hub

Tags: display, usb, displayport, thunderbolt-display

I have a 2020 MBA M1.

I bought a DP to Type C cable and a complementary hub to use my macbook with an external monitor in clamshell mode.

I found out everything works well when I connect the DP cable directly to the mac. However, I want to use it in clamshell mode and therefore need to connect it via a hub as I need to connect my mouse and keyboard too.

When I try to connect through the hub, it no display is detected but the mouse and the keyboard work.

Could it be that some USB type C cables do not support display transmission? Mine says it is Type C 3.2 and has speeds of 10GB/s.

If so, could someone recommend me a hub that would be affordable and suit my needs in a USB hub of 2 USB A ports and 1 type c port that supports DisplayPort to type C?

I cannot compromise on the port connected to the charger for a power delivery hub because I have seen hundreds of people saying they have bricked their macs by using that, and this seems to be more common with M1s as well.

Edit: Monitor is LG 24GL600F

Comment: What model is the monitor. What is the model of the current hub?

Comment: The hub must support Alt Mode display.  Targus makes one, I’ve seen it but not used it..

Comment: Alt Mode through a hub limits the monitor to 4K@60 Hz. So knowledge  of the resolution of the monitor would be helpful. In other words, without going through the hub, the Alt Mode limit would be 6K@60 Hz.

Comment: the monitor is a 144hz LG 24GL600f. I have edited the question with this information. I read the current hub's manual and it mentions that it does not support display, only data.

Comment: If the manual says it doesn’t support video, you’ve got the answer.  Time for a new hub.

Comment: does it have to be thunderbolt 3? All of thunderbolt docks are over $100. I am looking for something more affordable since I am not going to be making the full use of the dock for that price.

Comment: You should not need thunderbolt 3/4. Does the monitor have to connected by DP. Could you use HDMI? I ask because here are more HDMI hubs than DP hubs. From the way I read your question you do not want the hub to have its own power. In other words, you want the hub to be bus powered from the Mac. Is this correct?

Comment: i do not mind either, though the ones that are externally powered are expensive. HDMI does not support adaptive refresh rate.